# Scoped providers in Guice

Tags: java, guice

Does scoping work on Guice providers?  Suppose I have a `FooProvider` and bind like thus:

```
bind(Foo.class).toProvider(FooProvider.class).inScope(ServletScopes.REQUEST)
```

Will the `FooProvider` be instantiated once per request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `FooProvider` will be instantiated by Guice **only once**.

The scope applies to the binding, which means in your example that, if `Foo` is injected into another REQUEST-scoped object, Guice will call `FooProvider.get()` and will inject the returned `Foo` into that original object.

If you want the scope applied to FooProvider, then you would have to do something like that (NB: I haven't checked it but it should work):

```
bind(FooProvider.class).in(ServletScopes.REQUEST);
bind(Foo.class).toProvider(FooProvider.class).in(ServletScopes.REQUEST);
```

Answer (score 6):

It should be

```
bind(Foo.class).toProvider(FooProvider.class).in(ServletScopes.REQUEST);
```

but otherwise this should work as expected.

Comment: Initial tests show that this scopes both the provider and the provided object.  In most cases, this is probably desired.